# How can I plot a line vector in desmos?

Tags: desmos

If I go to [desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and type for example `5cos(45),5sin(45)` a point appears at 3.5, 3.5. I want this to be a line starting from the origin 0,0 but cannot see how to do so.

I see some point options when clicking the large dot to the left of the input field but no option for a line, as in the screen shot.

How can I make this point a vector line?

[image]

Comment: If you say $(t\cos 45, t\sin 45)$  or $(t,t)$ for that matter, you will be given a range for $t$ and a line segment whose length depends on the range of t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:
1: After the point, add `t` to the end. Make sure that you have not used `t` as a variable. [Example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kum9orh0l0)

2 After the point, add `,(0,0)`, and set lines to true. [Example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vqpwnyscd8)